# How to calculator exactly margin value of boder process in range slider?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I create a RangeSlider control:
XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="RangeSliderRepeatButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" Height="6" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RangeSliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
                        <Label x:Name="PART_ValueOfSlider" Content="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"
                                   Margin="0 -20 0 0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Red"/>
                        <Path x:Name="PART_Rectangle" Fill="Gray">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0 10 9" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"></RectangleGeometry>
                            </Path.Data>
                            <Path.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" BlurRadius="3" Color="Black" Opacity="0.4" Direction="270" />
                            </Path.Effect>
                        </Path>
                        <Path x:Name="PART_Traingle" Data="M 0 8 L 5 14 L 10 8 Z" Fill="Gray" >
                            <Path.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="0" Color="Black" Opacity="0.4" Direction="270" />
                            </Path.Effect>
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource LabledSliderThumbHoverBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Traingle" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource LabledSliderThumbHoverBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource LabledSliderThumbFocusesBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Traingle" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource LabledSliderThumbFocusesBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RangeSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Track Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource RangeSliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_Thumb" Style="{StaticResource RangeSliderThumbStyle}"/>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource RangeSliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF878889">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="47*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="353*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            BorderBrush="Black" 
                            Background="Black" 
                            Height="10" 
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Padding="2"
                            CornerRadius="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,5"/>

    <Border x:Name="progressBorder" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                            Background="Blue"  
                            BorderBrush="Blue" 
                            Height="6"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,7"
                            />
    <Slider x:Name="LowerSlider"
            Minimum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:RangeSlider}, Path=Minimum, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:RangeSlider}, Path=Maximum, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:RangeSlider}, Path=LowerValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Slider x:Name="UpperSlider"
            Minimum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:RangeSlider}, Path=Minimum, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:RangeSlider}, Path=Maximum, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:RangeSlider}, Path=UpperValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

RangeSlider.cs

```
public partial class RangeSlider : UserControl
{
    public RangeSlider()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(RangeSlider_LayoutUpdated);
    }

    void RangeSlider_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetProgressBorder();
    }

    private void SetProgressBorder()
    {
        double lowerPoint = (this.ActualWidth * (LowerValue - Minimum)) / (Maximum - Minimum);
        double upperPoint = (this.ActualWidth * (UpperValue - Minimum)) / (Maximum - Minimum);
        upperPoint = this.ActualWidth - upperPoint;

        progressBorder.Margin = new Thickness(lowerPoint, 0, upperPoint, 0);
    }

    public double Minimum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public double LowerValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public double UpperValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(10d, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(90d, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(100d, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged)));

    private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RangeSlider slider = (RangeSlider)d;
        if (e.Property == RangeSlider.LowerValueProperty)
        {
            slider.UpperSlider.Value = Math.Max(slider.UpperSlider.Value, slider.LowerSlider.Value);
        }
        else if (e.Property == RangeSlider.UpperValueProperty)
        {
            slider.LowerSlider.Value = Math.Min(slider.UpperSlider.Value, slider.LowerSlider.Value);
        }
        slider.SetProgressBorder();
    }
}
```

It work fine when `Label x:Name="PART_ValueOfSlider"`contain small value.
[image: work fine]

When `Label x:Name="PART_ValueOfSlider"` has big value, ProgressBorder display show not as I expected
[image: Not work fine yet]

How to set ProgressBorder work fine? Thanks for help me !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements in canvas will not influence for measure. So, use code:

```
<Canvas>
   <Label x:Name="PART_ValueOfSlider" Content="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"
        Margin="0 0 0 0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Foreground="Red">

     <Label.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
     </Label.RenderTransform>
      <Label.LayoutTransform>
           <TransformGroup>
              <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
            </TransformGroup>
      </Label.LayoutTransform>
    </Label>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using one slider Just Like You But Its work fine for me The Xaml code for the Slider

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TimeRangeSliderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange"/>

                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb">
                            <Thumb.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Red" 
                                               Stroke="Black"
                                               StrokeThickness="1" 
                                               Width="10"
                                               Height="18"
                                               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Thumb.Template>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type sliders:TimeRangeSlider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type sliders:TimeRangeSlider}">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Part_LowerSlider,Path=Value}"  Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="{Binding ElementName=Part_SelectedRect,Path=Margin}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PART_RIGHTTHUMPVALUE" Text="{Binding ElementName=Part_UpperSlider,Path=Value}"  Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="1" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="Part_SelectedRect"  Fill="Green" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Slider x:Name="Part_LowerSlider"
                            Minimum="{TemplateBinding Minimum}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding Maximum}"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding LowerValue}"
                            Template="{StaticResource TimeRangeSliderTemplate}"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

                        <Slider x:Name="Part_UpperSlider"
                            Minimum="{TemplateBinding Minimum}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding Maximum}"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding UpperValue}"
                            Template="{StaticResource TimeRangeSliderTemplate}"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the Cs file of the Xaml

```
 public class TimeRangeSlider : Control
{
    private const string PartName_LowerSlider = "Part_LowerSlider";
    private const string PartName_UpperSlider = "Part_UpperSlider";
    private const string PartName_SelectedRegion = "Part_SelectedRect";
    private const string PART_RIGHTTHUMPVALUE = "PART_RIGHTTHUMPVALUE";

    private Slider lowerSlider;
    private Slider upperSlider;
    Rectangle selectedRect;
    TextBlock rightText;

    public TimeRangeSlider()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TimeRangeSlider);
        this.Loaded += TimeRangeSlider_Loaded;
    }

    void TimeRangeSlider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lowerSlider.ValueChanged += LowerSlider_ValueChanged;
        upperSlider.ValueChanged += UpperSlider_ValueChanged;

        lowerSlider.Minimum = Minimum;
        lowerSlider.Maximum = Maximum;
        lowerSlider.Value = LowerValue;

        upperSlider.Minimum = Minimum;
        upperSlider.Maximum = Maximum;
        upperSlider.Value = UpperValue;

        SetView();
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        lowerSlider = this.GetTemplateChild(PartName_LowerSlider) as Slider;
        upperSlider = this.GetTemplateChild(PartName_UpperSlider) as Slider;
        selectedRect = this.GetTemplateChild(PartName_SelectedRegion) as Rectangle;
        rightText = this.GetTemplateChild(PART_RIGHTTHUMPVALUE) as TextBlock;

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }


    private void LowerSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        upperSlider.Value = Math.Max(upperSlider.Value, lowerSlider.Value);
        SetView();
    }

    private void UpperSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        lowerSlider.Value = Math.Min(upperSlider.Value, lowerSlider.Value);
        SetView();
    }

    private void SetView()
    {
        LowerValue = lowerSlider.Value;
        UpperValue = upperSlider.Value;

        var unit = lowerSlider.ActualWidth / Maximum;

        var leftMargin = LowerValue * unit;

        if (UpperValue > LowerValue)
        {
            var width = (UpperValue - LowerValue) * unit;
            selectedRect.Width = width;
        }

        selectedRect.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, 0, 0, 0);
        rightText.Margin = new Thickness(selectedRect.Width-20, 0, 0, 0);

    }

    public double Minimum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(TimeRangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

    public double LowerValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(double), typeof(TimeRangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

    public double UpperValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(double), typeof(TimeRangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(TimeRangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(1d));
}
```

and the usage of the control

```
 <SliderControl:TimeRangeSlider x:Name="slider" 
                           Margin="10" 
                           LowerValue="30"
                           UpperValue="70"
                           Minimum="0"
                           Maximum="100"
                           />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem occurs when add a Texblock above Thumb of Slider, the SelectedRect will be show not exactly

Comment: @MR.BJM I have edited My style with Textblock and SetView() Method Now try this one It will work.

Comment: I found a reason, that is the actual width of the slider changed because the actual width of grid in thumb has affected by actual width of label. My solution is use Label in Cavas because elements in canvas will not influence for measure. Thansks for your share !

Comment: Your slider works fine.Thansks for your share again!